# Swift: Order of Execution for Closures

Tags: swift

I have the following functions below.
When I run this, "hit2222" prints first, "hit4444" prints second, and "Image has been downloaded" prints last.

Shouldn't "Image has been downloaded" print first, since print("hit2222") is in the closure and getImages will only be done once every image has been downloaded?

```
func updateCurrentUser() {

    getImages(completion: { downloadedImages in
            print("hit2222")
    })

    print("hit444")
    self.currentUser.user.images = [UIImage(systemName: "star"), nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]

}

func getImageFromStorage(imagePath: String, completion: @escaping(UIImage?) -> Void) {
    // downloads one image from our database

    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
    let pathReference = storageRef.child(imagePath)

    // Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)
    pathReference.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("error hit : \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            let myImage = UIImage(data: data!)
            print("Image downloaded successfully")
            completion(myImage)
        }
    }
}

func getImages(completion: @escaping([UIImage?]) -> Void) {
    // downloads multiple images by calling getImageFromStorage multiple times

    var downloadedImages: [UIImage?] = []
    for i in 0...8 {
        let imagePath = "/img" + String(i)
        getImageFromStorage(imagePath: imagePath, completion: { myImage in
            downloadedImages.append(myImage)
        })
    }
    completion(downloadedImages)
}
```

Comment: It's likely that your `getImageFromStorage` does an async (like, with a `URLRequest`) operation (not shown in your posted code) since you're saying that it downloads something. So, that means that `getImageFromStorage` returns immediately, while another thread downloads the image.

Comment: @NewDev I updated the post with the getImageFromStorage code. I'm just confused on how to rewrite my code so that getImages() finishes executing, before we update self.currentUser.user.images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple async requests and you need to wait for all to complete, you could use a `DispatchGroup` to notify you when all the tasks in the group completed.

In your case, you need to wait until all images were downloaded before calling the `completion` function of `getImages`

```
func getImages(completion: @escaping([UIImage?]) -> Void) {

   var downloadedImages: [UIImage?] = []

   let downloadGroup = DispatchGroup()

   for i in 0...8 {

       downloadGroup.enter()

       let imagePath = "/img" + String(i)
       getImageFromStorage(imagePath: imagePath, completion: { myImage in
           downloadedImages.append(myImage)

           downloadGroup.leave()
       })
   }

   downloadGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
       // will be called when all requests are done
       completion(downloadedImages)
   }
}
```